# How do you take in 2 numbers and output their sum in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am getting into OCaml programming and having trouble with this

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this, demonstrated in the OCaml toplevel (the read-eval-print loop):

```
# print_int (read_int () + read_int ());;
18
44
62- : unit = ()
```

I typed in 18 and 44, then the toplevel printed 62.  It then printed the result of `print_int` (which is (), of type unit).

(It will probably be more effective for you to work through some tutorials before asking questions here. There are good tutorials at [OCaml.org](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials).)

**Update**

As the commenters are pointing out, there are quite a few subtleties in a full answer to your question. In particular, you don't really want to have more than one occurrence of `read_int ()` in a single expression because expression evaluation order is unspecified. In my defense, this is (at least partly) why I suggested starting with a tutorial to get up to speed before asking questions here.

Comment: let () = let a = read_int () in let b = read_int () in Printf.printf "The sum of %d and %d is %d\n" a b (a + b)

Comment: Note that `print_int (100 * read_int () + read_int ());;` with the same input may give you 4418 rather than 1844.